# C++ Initializer lists

Tags: c++, syntax, struct

I have to fill a `std::vector` with elements of type `struct MHD_OptionItem`.
This struct have this implementation:

```
struct MHD_OptionItem
{
    enum MHD_OPTION option;
    intptr_t value;
    void *ptr_value;
 };
```

I have tried this way:

```
 vector<struct MHD_OptionItem> iov;
 if(...)
     iov.push_back({ MHD_OPTION_NOTIFY_COMPLETED, requestCompleted, NULL });
 if(...)
     iov.push_back({ MHD_OPTION_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, connectionTimeout });
 [....]
```

but the g++ compiler, as expected, says to me:

`warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x`

I know that I can initialize a temporary struct and then pass it to the vector, but this method seems to me to be inefficient and not so elegant.

I can't change the struct inserting a constructor because this is not my code but a library included.

There is an elegant way to do this without using c++0x syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you cannot change the `struct` or you want to leave it a POD:

```
void f()
{
    struct {
        MHD_OptionItem operator ()(enum MHD_OPTION opt, intptr_t val, void *ptr = 0) {
            MHD_OptionItem x = {opt, val, ptr};
            return x;
        }
    } gen;

     vector<struct MHD_OptionItem> iov;
     if(...)
         iov.push_back(gen(MHD_OPTION_NOTIFY_COMPLETED, requestCompleted, NULL));
     if(...)
         iov.push_back(gen(MHD_OPTION_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, connectionTimeout));
     [....]
}
```

Another solution:

```
    struct Gen : MHD_OptionItem {
        Gen(enum MHD_OPTION opt, intptr_t val, void *ptr = 0) {
            option = opt;
            value = val;
            ptr_value ptr;
        }
    };

     vector<struct MHD_OptionItem> iov;
     if(...)
         iov.push_back(Gen(MHD_OPTION_NOTIFY_COMPLETED, requestCompleted, NULL));
     if(...)
         iov.push_back(Gen(MHD_OPTION_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, connectionTimeout));
     [....]
```

Comment: Effectively you are making 1 extra copy of `MHD_OptionItem`.

Comment: @iammilind: so what? It's an easy case for RVO.

Comment: What's up with the functor, why not just use an ordinary function?

Comment: It is similar to a solution I was thinking about

Comment: @Andreas: you cannot make local functions. Since I would like to give it a short name I want it to be a local.

Comment: It seems from the comment on my answer that the OP doesn't want to change the `struct` in any way. In that case, this answer is reasonable.

Comment: @iammilind: another solution to make you happy.

Comment: @iammilind the problem is that I can't change the struct in any way because it is a part of a library that I include in my code

Comment: +1, for the new solution. Very nice. I wish, I should have thought about it rather than wasting time on comments here. :\

Comment: the second solution is better than the first!

Comment: @Sebastiano: disagree. The first can be easily modified to do the `push_back` itself, shortening your code even further.

Comment: You should change `Gen()`  to use an initialization list.

Comment: @Andreas you cannot because the requirement is to not use C++0x.

Comment: but, what about this? `push_back((struct MHD_OptionItem){MHD_OPTION_NOTIFY_COMPLETED, requestCompleted, NULL})` should it work? In my opinion is not so elegant a cast each line.

Comment: @Sebastiano: it's C99 syntax, not C++03.

Comment: @ybungalobill: yes, but I don't understand why the compiler accept the syntax in my last comment without warnings and, instead, emits warnings with the syntax in the question

Comment: @Sebastiano: because g++ enables some GNU extensions by default. There are some flags do disable this behavior (see -pedantic?).

Comment: @ybungalobill: thanks, I was thinking that -Wall would be enough to have these warnings. Thanks for all replies

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a constructor for your struct.

```
struct MHD_OptionItem
{
    MHD_OptionItem(enum MHD_OPTION _option, intptr_t _value, void *_ptr_value)
    : option(_option), value(_value), ptr_value(_ptr_value) {}
    enum MHD_OPTION option;
    intptr_t value;
    void *ptr_value;
};
```

Then you can initialize this way:

```
ov.push_back(MHD_OptionItem(MHD_OPTION_NOTIFY_COMPLETED, requestCompleted, NULL));
```

Comment: The struct is not in my code. It's a library; i can't change this code

Comment: Isn't MHD_OptionItem a POD object?

Comment: @Sebastiano then see my proposal.

Answer (score 0):

How about having a constructor and copy constructor introduced,

```
struct MHD_OptionItem
{
  //...
  MHD_OptionItem(MHD_OPTION, intptr_t, void*);  // makes struct a non-POD
  MHD_OptionItem(const MHD_OptionItem&) // copy constructor
};
```

And using it for initialization,

```
iov.push_back(MHD_OptionItem(MHD_OPTION_NOTIFY_COMPLETED, requestCompleted, NULL));
```

Yes, you are introducing a temporary. But still the syntax remains elegant

Answer (score 0):

May be you can provide a constructor taking all the 3 parameters and then create it as follows:

```
iov.push_back(MHD_OptionItem( MHD_OPTION_NOTIFY_COMPLETED, requestCompleted, NULL));
```